# Link angular-cli to WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, npm, webstorm

I have a little problem with `npm` -- it is not linking the global modules to command line. Angluare-cli is installed as global module but WebStorm could not find it.

How could I tell WebStorm where to search for `angular-cli`?

Comment: Please try WebStorm 2016.2.1 - now you specify the path manually.

Comment: If I look into about, it shows me version 2016.2. I am not sure if it is the same, so I try to update, but there is no newer verision. But there is no option to set path to angular-cli in 'new project' form

Comment: I tested it in phpStrom (i use at work). Does it take some time phpstorm ist updated and inlcude the newest webstorm version?

Comment: PhpStorm 2016.2.1 is not yet released (but you can try the early access preview build now: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/08/phpstorm-2016-2-1-eap-162-1628/), but should be soon.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use Node v6 instead of v4. It would be wise to remove all global packages and empty your npm cache `npm cache clean` before uninstalling v4. After you install Node 6, install angular-cli globally again with `npm install -g angular-cli` and restart WebStorm. You should now be able to create a new Angular CLI project.